# asp:Menu hover makes "Security Information" pop up, how do I fix?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer-6, popup

[image]

I hover over my menu and a submenu expands, then this bad boy comes accross the screen. Is there something I can do in my website to prevent this?

IE6

aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/MyPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Tasks.aspx.cs" Inherits="UI_MyPage_Tasks" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <table>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>
                <asp:Menu ID="menu1" runat="server" OnMenuItemClick="menu1_MenuItemClick" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <cc:CustomUserControl ID="cuc1" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using VAC.Data;

public partial class UI_Patient_Tasks : BasePage
{
    MyDB db = new MyDB();
    private MenuItem UserRole1MenuItem { get { return GetMenu(Common.Role.UserRole1); } }
    private MenuItem UserRole2MenuItem { get { return GetMenu(Common.Role.UserRole2); } }

    private MenuItem GetMenu(string roleName)
    {
        int roleID = (from r in db.Roles where r.RoleName == roleName select r.RoleID).First();
        MenuItem main = new MenuItem(roleName + " Menu");
        foreach (CustomObject co in (from c in db.CustomObjects where c.RoleID == roleID orderby c.SortOrder select c))
            main.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem(co.Description, co.CustomObjectID.ToString()));
        return main;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            menu1.Items.Clear();
            if (User.IsInRole(Common.Role.UserRole1))
                menu1.Items.Add(UserRole1MenuItem);
            if (User.IsInRole(Common.Role.UserRole2))
                menu1.Items.Add(UserRole2MenuItem);
        }
    }
    protected void menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(e.Item.Value, out id))
        {
            cuc1.CustomObjectID = id;
        }
    }
}

    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Ok the only http references I could find were in my sitemaps.
`<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >` let me delete this.

Comment: You should probably post some markup code for your menu.

Comment: @Bill MaGriff, try running something like Fiddler http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/ whilst it's happening, it should tell you exactly what item(s) are trying to come down as http

Comment: @Rob, all I see are the locked HTTPS requests

Comment: No requests for *anything* over http at all? That is odd :=/ Even when you receive the warning dialog box and click "yes"?

Comment: Yup, there seems to be no difference between clicking yes or no. The site is still fully functional, just annoying.

Comment: So when clicking Yes, or No, you still get no requests made that you can see through Fiddler for resources that are non-secure?

Comment: All the requests are HTTPS. When the menu hover occurs no requests are made.

Comment: @Biff, I'm afraid I'm at a loss then. Given that it's IE6, it's possible it's making a request for a local resource like "about:blank" as a placeholder of some description. You may just have to put it down to "known issue in IE6" if your client can stomach that, or try alternative menu controls if they won't

Comment: Ugh, another IE6 "gotcha". Thanks for your insight Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're serving your site over ssl (i.e. `https://`) but serving some of the content, almost certainly something in the menu - such as an image over `http://`, hence you're receiving the "mixed mode" warning.

Review the markup for your menu and look for any `http://` URLs in the .aspx page (or possibly your codebehind if you build the menu dynamically) where there should be `https://` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all images or external resources are referenced via https.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray I found a fix.

The problem is in the PopOut_Show function. MS does some weird child frame thing.
I deleted it and it all works well!