# How do I override a javascript function that is inside another file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a problem with the asp:Menu control.
A menu control 2 levels deep does not play well with internet explorer on https.
I continually get an annoying popup.

I think in order to fix this I need to override a function in an automatically included script file.

change this

```
function PopOut_Show(panelId, hideScrollers, data) {
...
childFrame.src = (data.iframeUrl ? data.iframeUrl : "about:blank");
...
}
```

to this

```
function PopOut_Show(panelId, hideScrollers, data) {
...
if(data.iframeUrl)
childFrame.src = data.iframeUrl;
...
}
```

however I have no clue how I would hack apart the asp:menu control to fix microsoft's javascript in their control.

Is there a way I can just override the function to what I need it to be?

Comment: change function name in derived one. or add a null parameter to the function in derived one. :)Why overriding Javascript. Overload it simply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the overload later that should be the function that executes

```
function alerttest(){
alert("1");
}

function alerttest(){
alert("2");
}

alerttest();
```

Here is another answer:
[Overriding a JavaScript function while referencing the original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original)

Comment: Thanks this works to override the function. Unfortunately my code fix did not work. I'll have to see what the heck I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
childFrame.src = (data.iframeUrl ? data.iframeUrl : "about:blank");
```

Is identical to:

```
if(data.iframeUrl){
    childFrame.src = data.iframeUrl;
}
else{
    childFrame.src = 'about:blank';
}
```

Why do you need to override the function?

Comment: about:blank does not get put under https and I get this pop up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551438/aspmenu-hover-makes-security-information-pop-up-how-do-i-fix